# How to create a border for an ImageView without creating external XML file

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I know that I can add Borders to my ImageView by creating an XML drawable and set it as background to my ImageView. But however since it is an  ImageView, i need a picture on it. Whenever I tried to use *android:src=""* the picture is not settling property on ImageView. So Im putting the Image to the XML drawable . But I have multiple ImageViews, and I dont want to end up having multiple XML Layouts.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="5px" android:color="#0C0D00" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_viewplace2"
    android:bottom="3dp"
    android:left="3dp"
    android:right="3dp"
    android:top="3dp"
    />
```

the above code is the XML drawable and has an item with a picture. this works perfectly but i dont want to create an XML drawable like this for every imageview

[image]

Comment: what kind of border do you need? please show example

Comment: Can you add your relevant code to your question.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Please add relevant code and screenshots

Comment: why would you have multiple layouts , use same drawable shape .

Comment: @Kris but every drawable shape must have a different drawable picture